# Photoshop - Perspective floor that has depth

Tags: adobe-photoshop, perspective, art

I'm trying to create an image that is emulating a renaissance oil painting style. The scene involves a wall, a fountain and a floor. I have been given the wall and the fountain, and need to make the floor match. I'm not strong in drawing/painting in real life, but I do know photoshop somewhat well.

I started with a repeatable tile I found online:

[image]

Then I created the desired perspective I wanted (trying to match the fountain) using `filter`->`vanishing point`.

[image]

Which is one of my most clever tricks, but I found the result a bit flat (not to mention a bit blurry):

[image]

### Question

Is there a more reliable way or a method for creating a floor that has more potential for matching existing elements (such as the fountain) or that isn't as prone to fidelity loss? I also know my way around AI but that would veer too far on the other end (too sharp/clear) and would not look like an oil painting any more.

Here is the whole scene before the floor if that helps.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I would suggest you look at some renaissance paintings which include a tiled floor, and you should see the problem. [Here's one](https://render.fineartamerica.com/images/images-profile-flow/400/images/artworkimages/mediumlarge/1/a-banquet-dirck-hals.jpg).

Comment: @BillyKerr Hi. Nothing jumps out at me, probably not a good sign ha. I mean it doesn't have to be Sistine Chapel worthy, but just passable as professional. Perhaps it's not visible in my sample, but my scene is actually outdoors. It's like a courtyard. So I think having the white stone floor that is mono-color (not dual color as in your example) would still be the route to go. Open to suggestions though.

Comment: I've added an answer now, showing examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *Edit > Transform > Perspective* to distort the floor.  This will give you a one-point perspective with a vanishing point (shown by the blue lines in the example below). This will create the illusion of depth which is missing from your example.

You can see this kind of perspective used in paintings. In this example below, it also forms part of the composition of the painting. Note how the lines converge on the hat of the tallest figure in the group and how the people in the middle group in the scene seem to be tilted towards it.

[image]

Here's a very rough example using your images. Note I also cut around the font which is in the same perspective, which also helps the illusion.

[image]

Here I've enabled the crop tool, so you an see how the floor was distorted beyond the bounds of the canvas.

[image]Click to see larger

Comment: Interesting. My approach has "vanishing point" in its name, but yet it's still flat. Bit ironic, but maybe I'm not using it to its fullest. Your way is helpful as well. Thanks

Comment: @Arash - yes there are different ways to approach perspective. Your skew idea is similar to what some might call isometric perspective. It's a kind of flat perspective that doesn't give the same illusion of depth like the one point perspective used in old paintings.

Comment: @ArashHowaida your wanishing point is just really far away

Comment: @BillyKerr, or perhaps rather an *oblique* projection like *cabinet* projection? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#/media/File:Comparison_of_graphical_projections.svg

Answer (score 1):

To make it look like there's a proper perspective all items should fit together. The fountain bowl, the grating of the fountain well bottom, the floor grating,  and the pylons in the background are now like they are cut & pasted all from different images.

The vanishing points for sets of parallel lines are a good practical (but only partial) tool to get it right. The older answer shows a good place for one of the vanishing points, but the floor grating perspective is not enough, every item should be drawn in accordance with it.

No transformation converts an 2D image, which already has one kind of perspective to another perspective. The floor is an exception because it was originally a straight perpendicular view, so it can be converted like the older answer shows. The result, of course, is acceptable only if we can ignore the depth of all grooves and bumps on the floor tiling.  But making the rest look right with perspective transformations is a hopeless case. Redrawing everything as seen from the right different directions is the way to get it right. For example most of the pylons should have also something as seen on their sides except in case they are round. But then they should have proper shadings to make them look round.

A relatively easy shortcut is to make a coarse 3D model of the scene for ex. in SketchUP. Then find a good camera and light settings for rendering and use the rendering result as your perspective guide.

Another possibility is to make a coarse cardboard model and take a photo of it. The third way, maybe the hardest one and the one accepted also by purists, is to design the scene as flat engineering drawings and to make the traditional perspective construction from them. The hard part is to learn the method from some descriptive geometry book.

Also artist's perspective methods such as presented in common advanced drawing course books need much work, but they are still easier than construction from engineering drawings.